# How to integrate Eclipse with a build management tool?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have simple HelloWorld project in Eclipse. Usually I do 'run as application' my `HelloWorld.Java` file to execute the project. Now I want to invoke HelloWorld via a build management tool. But it has to be from Eclipse environment and not through a jar file.

This requirement sounds weird but that's what I am trying to do.

Comment: What do you mean by 'build management tool'?  Are you talking about something like Maven or Gradle or do you mean a CI Tool like Team City or Jenkins?  Also, what are you hoping to achieve with this integration?

Comment: I am considering Jenkins and Bamboo for now.

Comment: You have to define what you are trying to  do first. In the standard scenario, one uses eclipse for 'typing in the source code' and debugging and then put the code under version control. The CI tool then fetches the code from version control and tries building it and executing some tests on it. For building it may use information from the eclipse project settings or some other build environment like ant, maven or gradle. For new projects I would suggest to use gradle and also let gradle generate the eclipse projects for you

Comment: I understand how eclipse and jenkins are used as a standard practice. MY scenario is different. I am setting up a test execution environment where CI is integrated with SVN for the 'application to be tested'. At the same time I have another code in eclipse which performs tests on above application, In post build action of CI I want to execute this code from eclipse. And that's why my requirement is.

Comment: Currently I have achieved this using some robot kind of stuff, but I am looking for robust solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Jenkins, you will need SVN (or git).

So for the "Eclipse" environment, you will need subclipse in order to use SVN in Eclipse.

And have a look here :https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/hudsonjenkins-mylyn-builds-connector

Comment: The first link explains how to build (and modify) Jenkins which is not the scope of the question above.